# Cannot get syntax right for CollectionAssert

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am teaching myself about TDD on the following link; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416511%28VS.98%29.aspx

I am finding that some of the code is wrong which is disappointing given the topic is about testing, but I should not complain too much as it is good to learn from errors.

However I have never used; CollectionAssert before the the code below does not compile;

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Index_Get_RetrievesAllContactsFromRepository()
    {
        // Arrange
        Contact contact1 = GetContact(1, "Orlando", "Gee");
        Contact contact2 = GetContact(2, "Keith", "Harris");
        InMemoryContactRepository repository = new InMemoryContactRepository();
        repository.Add(contact1);
        repository.Add(contact2);
        var controller = GetHomeController(repository);

        // Act
        var result = controller.Index();

        // Assert
        var model = (ICollection<Contact>)result.ViewData.Model;
        CollectionAssert.Contains(model, contact1);
        CollectionAssert.Contains(model, contact2);
    }
```

The error message is
Error   4   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection' to 'System.Collections.ICollection'   C:\MVC3\Training\MvcContracts\MvcContracts.Tests\Controllers\HomeControllerTest.cs  94  39  MvcContracts.Tests

I have tried changing the cast from ICollection to IEnumerable, but that had effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
CollectionAssert.Contains(model.ToList(), contact1);
```

Comment: That doesn't work. ToList() is not available for an ICollection object. I also tried changing the cast from ICollection to IList on the previous line, but that did not work either.